# different forms of validates method in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

according to rails' built-in validation functions, what is the difference between these following two methods?

```
validates :password, :confirmation =>true
```

and

```
validates_confirmation_of :password
```

as far as I understand, the first was just introduced in rails version 3?
am I correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They both do the same exact thing, `validates_confirmation_of` is just one of the many short form helper methods for `validates`.

If you look at the source, you can see that the `validates` method is just written to handle all validators whereas `validates_confirmation_of` explicitly uses the `ConfirmationValidator`

I think `validates_confirmation_of` was introduced in Rails 2 so it's been around for quite a while.

Source comparison:

```
  def validates_confirmation_of(*attr_names)
    validates_with ConfirmationValidator, _merge_attributes(attr_names)
  end
```

and

```
  def validates(*attributes)
    defaults = attributes.extract_options!
    validations = defaults.slice!(*_validates_default_keys)

    raise ArgumentError, "You need to supply at least one attribute" if attributes.empty?
    raise ArgumentError, "You need to supply at least one validation" if validations.empty?

    defaults.merge!(:attributes => attributes)

    validations.each do |key, options|
      # LOOK AT THIS LINE
      key = "#{key.to_s.camelize}Validator"

      begin
        validator = key.include?('::') ? key.constantize : const_get(key)
      rescue NameError
        raise ArgumentError, "Unknown validator: '#{key}'"
      end

      # AND LOOK AT THIS LINE
      validates_with(validator, defaults.merge(_parse_validates_options(options)))
    end
  end
```